# SailsJS: accessing res.render in beforeCreate or afterCreate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I need to access the `res.render` function in `beforeCreate` in order to render an `html` template but appears that the `res object` is not passed to that function. Any ideas how can I do that?

As far as I know here is what afterCreate gets:

```
afterCreate: function(attrs, next) {
    // attrs is basically just the model
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use global Express' renderer, which resides in `sails.express.app.render`, so in your model it can be something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    sails.express.app.render('home', {locals: {}}, function(err, html) {
      console.log(html);
      next();
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Is that the recommended way to go?

Comment: I don't think this task is covered by current Sails' documentation, so it's not what you probably mean by 'recommended'. But Sails is still on the early stage of development, and there's a lot of subjective things about it, it's normal.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a couple of problems with this approach.  First, it won't have access to functions that live in `res` (most notable localization functions like `__`).  Second, `sails.express` isn't available in v0.10 (it'd be `sails.hooks.http.app`).  The only truly safe ways of doing this presently are a) use a custom controller action for model creation, instead of blueprint CRUD, or b) use the template-rendering module (e.g. `ejs`) directly in your `afterCreate` method.  All that being said, this definitely makes a case for a globally-accessible render method in Sails...

Comment: btw can you access the req and res objects in the beforeCreate method?

Comment: @PetarVasilev Nope, that was the original issue.

Comment: @bredikhin yes but in your answer you show access the .render function and to the actual req object - do you know where that resides?

Comment: @PetarVasilev It's the access to the Express renderer, not the request object: there may simply be no request in the model, think shell scripts and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Model is ***data*** layer of application, and it has nothing to do with request responding and views rendering.
`beforeCreate` and `afterCreate` are model lifecycle callbacks, and are used to do some logic when data changes.
Actually, you can create/change/delete model data from different places: sails console, controller, service etc. and these callbacks will be called.

Consider such case: If in your controller you call YourModel.create() method 100 times, then `beforeCreate` and `afterCreate` will be called 100 times, each. So in any case, it's not a good idea to render response in these callbacks.

Instead of this, you should manage request processing and response rendering in controllers.
If you want to do response after you create some data, it's easy:

```
YourModel.create({
  somefield: 'Nick',
  onemore: 'some string'
}).done(function(err, data) {

  // Error handling
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);

  // our model resord was created successfully!
  }else {
    console.log("model created:", data);

    // if you have nothing else to do here, let's render the view
    res.view();
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't want to render a reponse just send an email for which I need to render HTML template. Also, I am not using the controller to create the new entry in the model. It's all done automatically by SailsJS through CRUD so there is no other place to hook up my callback for sending email as far is I know.